# Why is autoref displaying a blank space in place of the "figure" text when referencing

Tags: floats, hyperref, subfloats, syntax, autoref

I am currently writing my masters thesis and ran into a little problem.

I have created a figure consisting of three smaller figures, each with their own subtexts, rendering the figures as 4.1a, 4.1b and 4.1c. When referencing these figures by the \autoref command, I get the result ( 4.1a), when the expecpted result would be (Figure 4.1a).

When referencing standalone figures earlier, the referencing works as expected. Figure 4.1 *does* show up in my list of figures, and refs do ref to the correct figures.

Why does this happen, and what can I do to fix it?

The figure:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[\centering The evolution of the Figma market share in comparison to competitors following its release.]{\includegraphics[width=0.40\textwidth]{figures/prototype/tools/PrototypingNEW.PNG}
\label{fig:figmaevolution}
}
\qquad
\subfloat[\centering Figma's market share for UI Prototyping, in comparison to the market in which it competes. ]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{figures/prototype/tools/Prototyping2NEW.PNG}
\label{fig:figmafourtimes}
}
\qquad
 \subfloat[\centering Results from each individual surveyed category, showing Figma as the clear collective victor. ]{\includegraphics[height=0.55\textwidth]{figures/prototype/tools/FigmaDominance.PNG}
\label{fig:figmadominance}
}
\caption{Results of UX/UI Survey 2020. Displays Figmas relative market share and versatility.}
\label{fig:figmafigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If I make your code compilable by employing the `article` document class and by loading the `graphicx`, `float`, `subfig`, and `hyperref` packages, I get the following error message: `! LaTeX Error: No counter 'fig:figmafigure' defined.` Moreover, since your sample code doesn't contain a `\ref` or `\autoref` statement, it's not possible *in principle* to replicate the issue you say you're trying to fix. Please clarify what's going on.

Comment: I believe the label is supposed to go after the caption.

Comment: I'm sorry. The example I copied into my question contained remnants of me trying to fix the problem.  I have updated it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever else you do, you must delete `\stepcounter{fig:figmafigure}` since this instruction throws an error message.

It would appear that you're using the `subfig` package. If this assumption is correct, you need to provide the instruction

```
\providecommand{\subfigureautorefname}{Figure}
```

in order to tell `\autoref` which prefix is should use when processing `\autoref{fig:figmaevolution}`. And, do place the subfigures' `\label` directives *inside* the `[...]` parts.

That said, you may want to employ the `cleveref` package and its user-level macro `\cref` instead of `\autoref`. For `\cref` can do just about anything that `\autoref` does, just better. For instance, `\cref` can take multiple arguments, whereas `\autoref` can not; see the example code below for an application.

Incidentally, I can see no valid reason for using doubled sets of curly braces to enclose the `\includegraphics` statements; single curly braces will do just fine. Last but not least, you must place `\label{fig:figmafigure}` *after* `\caption{}` if you intend the cross-reference the entire `figure` somewhere in the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption} % optional

\usepackage{hyperref}
\providecommand{\subfigureautorefname}{Figure} % <-- new
\hypersetup{colorlinks,allcolors=blue} % optional

\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref} % optional
\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{4} % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{1} % just for this example
\begin{figure}[ht!]     % '[ht!]' is safer than 'H'
\centering

\subfloat[Evolution of Figma's market share in comparison to its competitors', following its release.%
   \label{fig:figmaevolution}]%
   {\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{figures/prototype/tools/PrototypingNEW}}% % no need to specify '.png' extension
\hfill  % "\hfill" is better (and more robust!) than "\qquad"
\subfloat[Figma's market share for UI Prototyping, in comparison to the market in which it competes.%
   \label{fig:figmafourtimes}]%
   {\includegraphics[width=0.475\textwidth]{figures/prototype/tools/Prototyping2NEW}}

\subfloat[Results from each individual surveyed category, showing Figma as clear collective victor.%
   \label{fig:figmadominance}]%
   {\includegraphics[height=0.55\textwidth]{figures/prototype/tools/FigmaDominance}}

\caption{} \label{fig:figmafigure}
%% \stepcounter{fig:figmafigure}  % this instruction throws an error 
\end{figure}

A cross-reference to \autoref{fig:figmaevolution}.

Cross-references to \cref{fig:figmaevolution,fig:figmadominance}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your time and help.